# How to get/read the summary text from class definition

Tags: c#, json, xml, jsonschema

I want to read at runtime the summary text from the class

```
/// <summary>
/// Text I want to get 1
/// </summary>

class Hello
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Text I want to get 2
   /// </summary>
   string name {get;set;}
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
}
```

is that possible ?

I expect  to have a dictionary or something else that contains the name of class or the property
and his summary
something like this.

```
Dictionary<string, string> Dic ;
```

for example : {("Hello", "Text i want to get 1"),("name", "Text i want to get 2")}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I wouldn't expect comments to be in the compiled assembly.  What are you trying to accomplish and why?  How is JSON involved?

Comment: @David i'm trying to create à json schema  for my classes in my cs file. i want to read the summry of each class to join it to my schema

Comment: Why don't you create a custom attribute for description and use that instead of Comments

Comment: Have you looked at libraries that already do this for you, e.g. [_JsonSchema.Net.Generation_](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net.Generation/) ([docs](https://docs.json-everything.net/schema/schemagen/schema-generation/)) (disclaimer: I built it).

Answer (score 3):

Not a full answer but some steps helping to achieve your goal.

First of all you will need to enable generating the documentation file. Add the following to the .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Which will generate the file named `{AssemblyName}.xml` in the output folder ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#generatedocumentationfile)):

> The `GenerateDocumentationFile` property controls whether the compiler generates an XML documentation file for your library. If you set this property to true and you don't specify a file name via the `DocumentationFile` property, the generated XML file is placed in the same output directory as your assembly and has the same file name (but with an .xml extension).

which you then will be able to access for example via the following (sample):

```cs
var readAllText = 
    File.ReadAllText($"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml");
```

Then comes the hard part - parsing the file, which will look something like the following (for the sample code):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>NET8Console</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:Hello">
            <summary>
            Text I want to get 1
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="P:Hello.name">
            <summary>
            Text I want to get 2
            </summary>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

This task is actually already done by [`Swashbuckle`](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/tree/master) which can use xml comments to to generate Swagger descriptions, so I strongly suggest to look at how they are doing it - see [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/XmlComments](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/XmlComments) for example.

Another option is to look into [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) which allow to analyze your codebase (including XML comments) and generate some code files which will be compiled into the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `CodeDOM` and parse your sourcecode. This gives you a DOM-like structure of your code:

```
var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
var dom = provider.Parse(mySourceCode);
```

Now you can easily search your `DOM` for all kinds of statements, comments and whatnot. E.g. to get the comments for all your members use this:

```
var comments = dom.Types.Cast<CodeTypeDeclaration>()
    .SelectMany(x => x.Member.Cast<CodeTypeMember>())
    .SelectMany(x => x.Comments.Cast<CodeCommentStatement>());
```